# Event on Animation End Monotouch

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using Monotouch and XCODE.

I've created an animation using the following code and it is working:

```
img.AnimatedImages = myImageArray;
img.AnimationDuration =3;
img.StartAnimating();
```

What I am trying to achieve is to call a method when the animation has finished playing. I've created a timer using System.Timer but the problem is that it is not working when I am enabling it on user click. (It works if you enable it inside the constructor). Obviously it does not make sense to make a timer to loop every few milliseconds and check whether the img.isAnimating is still ongoing.

Does anyone has an idea how this can be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by setting this code:

```
public NSTimer myTimer;

// in ViewWillAppear method

myTimer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(3, delegate {myMethod();});

//create method that can be called by the timer

private void myMethod()
{

  myTimer.Invalidate();
  myTimer.Dispose();
  myTimer = null;

  //stop animation
}
```